# Select the first 20 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to select the first 20 columns from my table, without naming out each column in the select?

The columns are always ordered in the same way when I do a select, so there must be some underlying order.

Comment: is it really that difficult to just name the 20 columns?

Comment: Construct it dynamically querying `all_tab_columns`

Comment: if you're doing it A LOT for the same table, just create a view

Comment: This *can* be done dynamically in a single query but it would be difficult to setup.  It wouldn't be worth the effort unless you were constantly running this queries on many different tables.

Answer (score 1):

The below query forms the SQL for you. It uses the dictionary table `all_tab_columns` to fetch the column names for the table.

```
SELECT ' SELECT '
  || REPLACE(LISTAGG(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY column_id),',',','
  ||CHR(10))
  || ' FROM YOUR_TABLE'
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE owner   ='YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
AND table_name='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND column_id <= 20;
```

Comment: Thanks, This produces in the query result, the syntax which I then need to copy, paste into the worksheet and run. Is it possible to add some more code to the above which means it will also run the query?

Comment: How do you execute the query? In SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes, SQL developer.

Answer (score -1):

There is a table in a SQL Server database called sysColumns that records all the columns in every table. I think it is a SQL standard and should be in Oracle too.

EDIT: thanks to comment from @davegreen100, this table is in Oracle but is named `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

try running `Select * from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` and see what the results are, and work from there.

If it's there (in Oracle), you will eventually end up with something like

```
Select name from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
Where id = @tableId  -- <--- the id of the table 
   and colOrder <= 20
```

Your final SQL will be probably have to be generated dynamically using the output from the above

Comment: in oracle the table is DBA_TAB_COLUMNS

Answer (score -1):

you can use column index instead of column name like select 0,1,2,.....

Comment: Did you try it once?

Comment: yes .but a problem that does not give the output column names